# How do you append objects in a hash table with the name of the objects as the key?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashtable

I am relatively new to Python and I need help with implementing Hash table class using Pythons built-in dictionary and appending objects of a file to the hash table and store the name of the objects as key.

I want to read my file(which contains names, phone numbers and email addresses), make objects and add them to the hash table with the name as the key. I tried this:

```
with open("names.csv", "r") as names_file:
    for line in names_file.readlines():
        person = Person(line)
        q = HashtableDict(1000)
        q.store(key=person.name, data=person)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work when trying to search for a key(name) with the find method which means that something went wrong with storing the objects to the hash table. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating hash table per line in csv.

You need to create it only **once**

```
q = HashtableDict(1000)

with open("names.csv", "r") as names_file:
    for line in names_file.readlines():
        person = Person(line)
        q.store(key=person.name, data=person)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-creating a new `HashtableDict` for each line in the csv.

After the entire loop, you are left with the last created `HashtableDict` as `q`. It will only contain the name of the last person.